# Dynamics CRM Change Status Workflow error

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, status

I have a workflow that that runs to update the status of a Case record to Resolved. However, the workflow gets put into status 'waiting' and contains a generic error message. When looking at the system job message it says:

[image: Error Message]

This has worked on another system (as all I am doing is updating a status) so I assume it has something to do with the customizations in place.

Has anyone else ever come across this and how did you resolve it?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**

I have created a new organisation to test out any possible solutions and to narrow down what might be happening.

I created a workflow on the blank organisation and a test case record to try it out on. It worked fine as expected.

I then imported the customizations that are on my customers system. Did the same again and it worked fine.

I then created a new case record and tried the original workflow, this did not work.

I then added a workflow that does the same as the first workflow and tried it on the pre customizations record, it worked.

I then tried the new workflow on the new record and once again this did not work.

It is therefore appearing that the workflows are not working on any records post customization import.

Has anyone come across this before, and what steps were taken to resolve?

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If you have the possibility to look at the registered plugins, then search for a plugin registered on the message `SetState` or `SetStateDynamicEntity` for the entity case (incident).

I assume there is a plugin which fails in your case. This is the reason for your error message.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have checked the registered plugins and there are none that are registered against the incident entity.

Comment: @Brett what`s about other dependent entities?

Comment: No there isn't, any other possible ideas? Thanks

Comment: Update added above, any  suggestions will be greatly appreciated